# How do I prove that $\lim_{x\to 2} 7x-3 \neq 8$?

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Didn't find anything by googling.
So far I worked through proving this by assuming the limit is 8 until there is a contradiction.
Eventually I got:
$\epsilon > \left | 7x-3-11 \right |$ and $\epsilon > \left | 7x-11 \right |$ which seems like a contradiction. Is this correct? If so how do I proceed?

Comment: You need to find an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that no (punctured) $\delta$-window around $x = 2$ maps (under $x \mapsto 7x-3$) entirely within the $\varepsilon$-window around $8$, no matter how small $\delta$ is.

Comment: Hint:  If $|(7x-3) - 8| < \epsilon$ then $-\epsilon < (7x-11)< \epsilon$ and $11-\epsilon < 7x < 11 + \epsilon$ and $1\frac 34 -\frac\epsilon{7}<x< 1\frac 34 +\frac {\epsilon}7$ and $|x-1\frac 34| < \frac \epsilon 7$.  What happes if we pick an $\epsilon$  so small  and an $x$ so that $1\frac 34 + \frac {\epsilon}7 < x < 2$.  Do you see how that would be a problem?

Comment: If $|x-2|< \gamma$ then $2-\gamma<x<2+\gamma$. So $11-7\gamma < 7x-3<11 + 7\gamma$.  If $\epsilon < 3$ and $\gamma < \frac 17(3-\epsilon)$ we have $8 + \epsilon < 11-7\gamma < 7x-3$.  So if we have a $0<\epsilon<3$ and for any $\delta > 0$ if we choose $|x-2|<\min(\delta, \frac 17(3-\epsilon))\le \delta$ the we will have $8+\epsilon < 7x-3$ and $|(7x-3)-8| > \epsilon$ meaning that for some $\epsilon$, finding a $\delta$ where $|x-2|<\delta \implies $|(7x-3)-8| < \epsilon$ is impossible.

Comment: ..... or we could just prove $\lim 7x-3 = 11$....  (that is assuming two limits are impossible.... which is always a good exercise to prove.)

Comment: So much Information! Thank you! I heard that limits are unique and two limits cannot co-exist for the same point. However, it's interesting to think about a circle. For each x in the circle(with few exceptions, I think), y approaches 2 points. How would that work? Unless circle functions are considered multivariable functions, which have different definition.